# AltBeacon : onBeaconServiceConnect not called when BeaconConsumer Binded From DidEnterRegion BootstrapNotifier callback

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I'm writing an Android App custom Class that utilises AltBeacon's Android-Beacon-Library.

Instead of posting the class, I am reproducing the problem using the reference implementation samples provided with the library.

If I activate both monitoring (by implementing a RegionBootstrap) and ranging beaconManager.bind(new BeaconConsumer()...) directly in onCreate(), everything works perfectly.

I would like however to start ranging **only when a Beacon enters region**, so in didEnterRegion(Region arg0) callback of the RegionBootstrap, but when I do so, onBeaconServiceConnect() is never called. I believe doing it this way would be more efficient in terms of battery consumption.

I have tried force executing on the main thread as well as using delayed timers but it didn't work.

Anyone could get this to work ? Any help appreciated!

```
public class BeaconReferenceApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidProximityReferenceApplication";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
    BeaconManager beaconManager;
    Context context = this;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        // Setup beacon layout - should be done once only
        List<BeaconParser> bp = beaconManager.getBeaconParsers();
        bp.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion", null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

        // THIS WORKS
        bindBeaconConsumer();
    }

    public void bindBeaconConsumer() {
        beaconManager.bind(new BeaconConsumer() {
            @Override
            public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
                // ISSUE : Does not pass here when bindBeaconConsumer() is called from didEnterRegion

                // Set Range Notifier and start ranging
            }

            @Override
            public Context getApplicationContext() {
                return context;
            }

            @Override
            public void unbindService(ServiceConnection serviceConnection) {
                context.unbindService(serviceConnection);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, int i) {
                return context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");

        // THIS DOESN'T WORK : onBeaconServiceConnect() never called
        // bindBeaconConsumer();
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason calling `bindBeaconConsumer()` doesn't work in the monitoring callback is because by the time it executes, the class is already bound to the service.  If you look at LogCat, you will see a warning message about this.  Since it is already bound, the code does not get a callback to `onBeaconServiceConnect()`.

Why is it already bound?  Because of the line below:

```
regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
```

The `RegionBootsrap` class does a bind operation behind the scenes, which executes in a second or so.

The easiest way to fix this is to remove the call to `bindBeaconConsumer()` in the `didEnterRegion` method and instead just call `beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(...)`.  You don't need to bind again because by that point, the service is already bound.